# Get notified when the user is viewing a certain item in a scroll view and scroll to desired view

Tags: android

I have a (vertical) linear layout inside a scroll view. The linear layout houses a set of other layouts.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <layout1></layout1>
        <layout2></layout2>
        <layout3></layout3>
        <layout4></layout4>
    <LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I would like to be notified when a certain child of the linear layout is in view and be able to scroll to a desired layout.

Is there any way to achieve that?